# Binary search (bisection method) - is it worth checking continuity

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, continuity

I am implementing a rather simple matlab code, that gets a function $f$ and 3 real numbers $a,b, \epsilon$ where $\epsilon >0$ is a very small positive number (for instance, no larger than $10^{-10}$) and $b>a$.  and returns $\alpha \in [a,b]$ such that $|f(\alpha)|<\epsilon$ if indeed there is such an $\alpha$.

I am required to do this using bisection method.

Checking if indeed $f(a)f(b)<0$ can be done in $O(1)$ and is something trivial to do.

However, in the case where $f$ is not continuous, even if the previous term is met, we can't be sure if there is a root, so there is no point running bisection method because we can't guarantee convergence.

So my question is - is it worth checking (numerically) that $f$ is continuous? Wouldn't that increase the runtime so much that it isn't worth the effort? and also how would this be done?

Comment: How can you check the continuity numerically?

Comment: I was thinking something similar to deriving numerically. Something along the lines of: "is $|f(x+\delta)-f(x)|<\epsilon_2$ for very small $\delta, \epsilon_2$". To check like that for every $x \in [a,b]$

Comment: This seems very very slow. But without continuity how can i assure convergence?

Comment: In fact if it is not continuous, the convergence is not guaranteed.

Comment: Also, note that your method on checking continuity is not practical, since you need to check it for a large large set.

Comment: My suggestion: assume the function is continuous!

Comment: Thank you Mohammad. I guess that there is no way around it and I just need to assume valid input.

Comment: How is the function being given to you? Is it 
(1) a set of $(x, f(x)$ points; or 
(2) the implementation of some function that can be called from your code; or
(3) some other specific format?

For (1) you can assume continuity. For (2) it could be tricky, and fail. For (3) maybe you can find the points of discontinuity.

Comment: It is given by it's formula. As soon as the program starts, there will be an input box saying "Please enter a function" and then the user will enter, for example, $x\sin(x)$ or something similar. So I guess that's $(2)$

Comment: I'd suggest just running the bisection method, regardless of the input. If you don't find a zero of the function after some number of iterations, issue an error message saying that the input function is somehow defective. The number of iterations $n$ should be such that $(b-a)*2^{-n} < \text{machine epsilon}$, or something like that. Trying to test for continuity seems futile. Also, the iteration might work, sometimes, even if the input function is discontinuous, so let it.